# React Conditional Rendering on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of poem titles and images within article HTML tags. Whenever a user clicks on an article, I want a modal to show the poem verses. As of now whenever an article is clicked, the modals for every poem opens. How do I open the modals one at a time? This is my first time using React.

Link to my codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/and-air-52dpo?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate each Poem card to a component, and put the state inside them. 
 By using state on parent component as you did, it cause all poem card depend on same state.

I've forked your codesandbox, and fixed them. You can check it.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/and-air-543tl

Answer (score 0):

You're using a single `show` variable in your `Poems` component.
This doesn't allow to show a single one of your modals, as all of them are referenced to this same variable.

I would use an integer in the `Poems`'s state - rather than the boolean `show` - to store the currently presented modal.
The best option for this integer is probably the poem's index, as [you should anyway add](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component) to your `map` function:

```
const listItems = data.map((poem, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
        // The rest of your code is the same

        <Modal
          show={this.state.currentModal === index} // only this property was updated
          onClose={this.showModal}
          title={poem.title}
        >
            // modal code
        </Modal>
    </React.Fragment>
))
```